# Where is sitemap.txt.jsp in AEM?

Tags: search, adobe, aem

I'm trying to integrate Search and Promote with AEM. The [docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/integration/marketing-cloud/search-and-promote.html) say to generate a sitemap by copying the following file "/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/sitemap.txt.jsp".

This doesn't exist for me. I'm using 6.2.
Is "/libs/foundation/components/sitemap/sitemap.jsp" what I should be looking for?

Comment: please raise a ticket with Adobe for the documentation correction problem. Also for any S&P page crawling you can use domain as entry point.

Comment: The `/libs/foundation/components/sitemap/sitemap.jsp` component usage can be found at [geometrixx sitemap](http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/sitemap.html)

Comment: @VAr do I still need a sitemap for S&P to crawl correctly?

Comment: @VAr Do you know where I can raise a ticket? I keep getting directed to community forums and documentation when I go to help sections.

Comment: For Client support it will be something like [https://daycare.day.com/home/your/client/customer_services/ticketnumber.html](https://daycare.day.com/home/your/client/customer_services/ticketnumber.html)  url with your client purchase account login. for public you can visit at [day care contact](https://daycare.day.com/public/contact.html) . For Adobe document update you can raise an issue in [adobe forums](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.html)